# Laravel form does not assign corresponding values to the fields of a form

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

im in deep trouble. 
im using ajax to submit a form in laravel. when i submit a form it does not submit correctly because each field of laravel does not have its assigned value. 
first field of laravel form is method field, when i inspect my submitted data through chrome it shows mothod field is empty and request assign my mothod field value to the very next field of the form.
in the same way each field dont have its corresponding value. 
i attached snapshot of chrome inspection please look into it.
here is my code for a form.

```
<form id="add_car_2" class="s-submit clearfix" method="POST">
                                {{method_field('patch')}}
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="b-submit__main-element wow zoomInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="security_system" id="security_system" />
                                            <label class="s-submitCheckLabel" for="security_system"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></label>
                                            <label class="s-submitCheck" for="security_system">Security System</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="b-submit__main-element wow zoomInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="air_bag" id="air_bag" />
                                            <label class="s-submitCheckLabel" for="air_bag"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></label>
                                                <label class="s-submitCheck" for="air_bag">Air Bag</label>
                                            </div>
                               </div>

    </form>
```

here is my ajax function to submit this form.

```
$("#add_car_2").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url=/cars/ + $('#car_id').data('carid');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',            
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        success: function (data, status){
           console.log(data);
           console.log(status);    
        }

    });    
});
```

when i submit this form through ajax it shows failed to submit because each field of form does not have its correct value[image]

Comment: Why not use this package and build the form properly using that? - https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html

Comment: wow, you're sloppy. No punctuation. no aligned html (missing closing div btw). Sorry, it's too hard for me to search for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="add_car_2" class="s-submit clearfix" method="POST">
                            {{csrf_field()}}
                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="b-submit__main-element wow zoomInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="security_system" id="security_system" />
                                        <label class="s-submitCheckLabel" for="security_system"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></label>
                                        <label class="s-submitCheck" for="security_system">Security System</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="b-submit__main-element wow zoomInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="air_bag" id="air_bag" />
                                        <label class="s-submitCheckLabel" for="air_bag"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></label>
                                            <label class="s-submitCheck" for="air_bag">Air Bag</label>
                                        </div>
                           </div>

</form>
```

Comment: i also used  {{csrf_field()}} field. problem is same.

Comment: basically each field don't have its corresponding value.